# VB6 - Call Stored Procedure with recordset output on SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, vb6, ado, adodb

I'm supposed to run a procedure that results in a recordset. I found some code online.
I used this code:

```
Dim cnAdoDB As ADODB.Connection
Dim StrConnection As String
Dim ACmd As ADODB.Command
Dim TempRS As ADODB.Recordset
Dim RecordNumber As Long
 
Set cnAdoDB = New ADODB.Connection
StrConnection = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;Initial Catalog=DB-Name;Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
 
cnAdoDB.ConnectionString = StrConnection
cnAdoDB.Open
cnAdoDB.CursorLocation = adUseClient

 
Set ACmd = New ADODB.Command
 
ACmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
ACmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[st_log_GetDatiTracciabilitaLottoArticolo]"
 
ACmd.Parameters.Append ACmd.CreateParameter("@ReturnValue", adInteger, adParamReturnValue)
ACmd.Parameters.Append ACmd.CreateParameter("@vLotto", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, "2022085001")
ACmd.Parameters.Append ACmd.CreateParameter("@vCodArticolo", adVarChar, adParamInput, 32, "A014L628")
ACmd.Parameters.Append ACmd.CreateParameter("@vDataOraPompa", adDate, adParamInput, , Null)
 
 
Set ACmd.ActiveConnection = cnAdoDB
 
Set TempRS = ACmd.Execute(RecordNumber)`
```

ADODB.Recordset RecordCount property always returns -1:
[image]

The TempRS recordset is empty but the "RecordNumber" variable has a value of 2 as the result records really are.

Comment: I'm not sure your question ... you end by saying "as the results really are" ... really are what? Is your recordset populated or empty? What do you want here? FWIW, record counts tend to be tricky in this type of ADO code. (also by the way I left an erroneous backtick at the end of your code when I edited it to add code formatting).

Comment: Your recordset is closed. This happens when the stored procedure does not return any data. If it does when called from SSMS, then you are not passing your parameters properly. Most likely this is due to the last parameter. In any case, your `RecordNumber` would contain the number of records affected by the stored procedure, not the number of records in the returned recordset.

Answer (score -1):

Make it a habit to never rely on the .RecordCount property. It's too situational. From the [help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/recordcount-property-ado?view=sql-server-ver16):

> Use the RecordCount property to find out how many records are in a
> Recordset object. **The property returns -1 when ADO cannot determine**
> **the number of records or if the provider or cursor type does not**
> **support RecordCount**. Reading the RecordCount property on a closed
> Recordset causes an error.

Your code also has errors:

```
ACmd.Parameters.Append ACmd.CreateParameter("@vLotto", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, "2022085001")
ACmd.Parameters.Append ACmd.CreateParameter("@vCodArticolo", adVarChar, adParamInput, 32, "A014L628")
```

Instead of "20" and "32" *(presumably the defined size)*, the Parameter object expects that **actual** length of the passed data, i.e.

```
ACmd.Parameters.Append ACmd.CreateParameter("@vLotto", adVarChar, adParamInput, Len("2022085001"), "2022085001")
ACmd.Parameters.Append ACmd.CreateParameter("@vCodArticolo", adVarChar, adParamInput, Len("A014L628"), "A014L628")
```

Comment: The Size property is defined in the docs like this:  `Use the Size property to determine the maximum size for values written to or read from the Value property`.  So while your example code will not likely fail, the `Len` idea isn't really needed.  I have always passed the max size as defined in the DB.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the replies. I tried to execute the procedure directly from SQLManager, and the output recordset contains 2 records. If you look in the attached image, you find the "RecordNumber" variable at 2, so i thought the vb code and the parameters passed to the procedure were correct. I can try passing the stored procedure the right string length but I guess it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I tried putting the right length of the strings, but the result doesn't change.